# Insertion sort revised with output to console

Tags: c#, performance, rags-to-riches, insertion-sort

I took the question [Performing insertion sort in C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/59968/18427) and tidied it up a bit, then I thought about the use of the arrays and was wondering if it worked, and it does.

So now I have 3 static methods in a simple `Program` class to run from the console, just to check 15 numbers quickly.  It's not very efficient.

What can be done to make it more efficient? I am assuming taking out the `PrintIntegerArray` from inside the `PerformInsertionSort` method for larger arrays would help with that.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[15] {9,4,13,42,56,21,1,19,42,42,40,109,3,8,99};

        Console.WriteLine("Final OutPut");
        PrintIntegerArray(PerformInsertionSort(numbers));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int[] PerformInsertionSort(int[] inputArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j > 0; j--)
            {
                if (inputArray[j - 1] > inputArray[j])
                {
                    int temp = inputArray[j - 1];
                    inputArray[j - 1] = inputArray[j];
                    inputArray[j] = temp;
                }
                PrintIntegerArray(inputArray);
            }
        }
        return inputArray;   
    }

    public static void PrintIntegerArray(int[] array)
    {
        foreach (int i in array)
        {
            Console.Write(i.ToString() + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End of Array");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare the size of the array here:

> ```
> int[] numbers = new int[15] {9,4,13,42,56,21,1,19,42,42,40,109,3,8,99};
> ```

You can just write,

```
var numbers = new[] { ... };
```

---

You can skirt the issues with `PrintIntegerArray` by using `string.Join`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
```

---

`PrintIntegerArray` doesn't need to be public. Limit visibility where possible.

---

I would make it clear that `PerformInsertionSort` is modifying the array by changing its return type to `void`. This could go either way, as it is nice to be able to chain method calls, but here I would err on the side of `void`.

Answer (score 3):

One obvious optimization is to avoid many unnecessary swaps:

```
        int j;
        value_to_insert = inputArray[i];
        for (j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            if (inputArray[j - 1] > value_to_insert)
            {
                inputArray[j] = inputArray[j - 1];
            }
        }
        inputArray[j] = value_to_insert;
```

Just one assignment instead of 3.

Besides (sorry for repeating my mantra on a naked loops), now it becomes obvious that an inner loop implements some sort of a `shift` algorithm. Better to factor it out.

It is also very well possible that separating `find` and `shift` phases may also speed it up:

```
        value_to_insert = inputArray[i];
        int j = upper_bound(inputArray, inputArray + i, value_to_insert);
        shift(inputArray + j, input_array + i, 1);
        inputArray[j] = value_to_insert;
```

because both methods *could* be implemented as intrinsics.

Comment: I am not sure that I am following your `upper_bound` and shifting?  I don't think that `upper_bound` is C#... just a little confused.

Comment: your first block of code is still doing 3 assignments, just in different places, I am not following you completely.

Comment: `upper_bound` is an algorithm. You can implement it in C#, or as an intrinsic, or whatever way fits. The point is, it does a very particular job, pops out all over the place (i.e. very reusable), and has a name.

Comment: Re 3 assignments in the first block: two of them are not inside the loop. The loop performs just one assignment per iteration.

Comment: ok that makes sense, it will find where it needs to go in the array before actually inserting it back into the array.

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: I will look into the Upper Bound algorithms and try to get that stuff figured out as well. thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the last two lines in `PrintIntegerArray()` are necessary.  If the function is supposed to print the array, then it should do just that.  If it's even necessary, you can always do the last output in `main()` after the function call.  And assuming that `ReadLine()` serves as a "pause", that can also just stay in `main()`.  You're otherwise doing it twice.

I would also add a space after each comma in the array initialization.  It both maintains consistency and makes it easier to read each separate number.  If there are too many or there *can* be too many, then consider wrapping the line in some way.

Very minor thing: in the final output, I'd change "OutPut" to "Output"; it is just one word.

Comment: In other words, use a unit test instead of the console.

Comment: the printing of the `End of Array` was to skirt the issue of having a comma as the last character... and that would be done every time the method is called, but I agree that the readline should be done where necessary and not in the method.

Comment: @Malachi: I see.  One workaround would be to have an `if` in there, which may make it not-so-clean.  However, given the circumstances, it shouldn't quite hurt branch prediction.